# Windows Update and/or BITS is eating my bandwidth even though I changed update group policies

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I went through all the trouble of editing the group policy so that Windows Update will ask me instead of automatically download updates (it usually does it while I'm gaming, so my ping sky-rockets), but the process `Service Host: Local System` is still eating my bandwidth.

I checked `System Settings > Windows Update` and it isn't downloading anything (it just says "Updates are ready to download" and shows a download button), which makes me think **BITS** *(Intelligent Background Transfer Service)* is somehow eating my bandwidth.

Any ideas on how can I stop this?

**EDIT:** Here's an image of the processes under `Service Host: Local System`

[image]

Comment: try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/224981/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-uploading-updates-to-other-pcs-over-the-internet/

Comment: I wrote that I went through the trouble of disabling automatic updates already. I literally used that same link you just posted.

Comment: you haven't posted that you disabled this. try the Get-BitsTransfer cmdlet to see what is BITS doing